# regex match uneascaped quoted string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match quoted strings in a sentence with regex, matching strings closed with quotes and also string at end of sentence which have only opening quotes.

For example in the sentence `concat("hello ",  name, "how are`, I will match  `"hello"` and `"how are`.

This is my regex which works well

```
reg = /"[^"]*"?/g
input = 'concat("hello ",  name, "how are';
[...input.matchAll(reg)].map(m => m[0])
/** output:
[ 
  '"hello "', 
  '"how are' 
]


 */
```

but it fails when there is a backslashed quote. 
For example for the sentence: 
`concat("say \"hello\" to ",  name, "and to` I would like to match `"say \"hello\" to"`, and  `"and to`, but thhis is what the regex matches:

```
reg = /"[^"]*"?/g
input = 'concat("say \\"hello\\" to ",  name, "and to'
[...input.matchAll(reg)].map(m => m[0])
/** output (not the one I am trying to get):
[ 
  '"say \\"', 
  '" to "', 
  '"and to' 
]
 */
```

I tried adding to regex `(?<!\\)` before every `"`, so it matches only quotes that are no backslashed, but still get wrong result:

```
reg = /(?<!\\)"[^(?<!\\)"]*(?<!\\)"?/g
input = 'concat("say \\"hello\\" to ",  name, "and to'
[...input.matchAll(reg)].map(m => m[0])
/** result:
[ 
  '"say ', 
  '",  name, "' 
]

*/
```

what would be the correct regex?

Comment: I see the behavior is totally normal, because the sentence `"say \\"` already started by a quote and ended by a quote too so that's what you provided for your regex (and the same for the other matches), 
so here you have to analyse the use case because it's not clear if you want to ignore the first quote of the function concat inside the provided input string or not ? It would be better too if you provide an expected values so we can also understand the full expectations

Comment: in the sentence:
`concat("say \"hello\" to ",  name, "and to` I would like to match `"say \"hello\" to", and "and to` (just like if you type a string in the editor the editor will consider the backslashed quotes as part of the quoted string, and not as closing the string

Comment: yes exactly that's what i understood through the examples above, the problème is that the provided strings in your `concat(..)` is provided by the same double quote input string which is an error even in JS language interpreter, so i suggest to use single quote inside double quote or vise versa (example: instead of `concat(".."hello"..")` you can make `concat("..'hello'..")` or `concat('.."hello"..')` and you provide a regexp to distinct between the both cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for:

```js
const reg = /"(?:\\\\|\\"|[^"])*"?/g;
const input1 = 'concat("say \\"hello\\" to ",  name, "and to';
const input2 = 'CONCAT("\\\\", name';
console.log([...input1.matchAll(reg)].map(m => m[0]));
console.log([...input2.matchAll(reg)].map(m => m[0]));
```

**Edit:** I updated the regex to account for the case where the backslash may itself be escaped

Comment: thanks! this solves most cases, but when having a string that contains a backslashed backslash, it gets confused,
example: `input = 'CONCAT("\\\\", name'`, expected match: `['"\\\\"']`, actual match: `[ '"\\\\", name' ]`

Comment: @dina No problem! I just added an edit to my answer - it should handle that case now too